# Close "x" icon gets clipped inside the containing dialog

Tags: bug, jobs, design

When you are looking at a job offer from StackOverflow in Careers there is a "Not sure yet? Ask Stack Overflow a question" link that opens a modal window. I have noticed that there is a quarter of a "close" window in the upper right corner:

[image]

I guess that this should be a full button that pops outside the window, but for some reason gets clipped. The button works as expected if you have aim enough to click it, by the way. :-)